# Exception handling with multiple futures from ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using a ScheduledExecutorService to which I add both submit Runnables as well as scheduled Runnables (using scheduleWithFixedDelay).
The intention is to have very long running processes and thus non of my runnables have a defined lifetime. I basically want the main thread to only react to exceptions and interruptions.
The scheduled tasks are critical, e.g. generating heatbeats, and thus if any thread throw a runtimeexception I want to log the exception, abort all other threads and close the program.

How should I handle the exceptions? The ScheduledExecutorService swallows all the exceptions unless I run Future.get().

Looping through the futures, like below, does not work. If the first item in the futures list doesn't return any errors that will block the thread from listening on the other threads that might return error.

```
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
    future.get();
}
```

One option would be looping through the futures asking if they are done, like below, but I don't really like this solution. I need to add a thread sleep and thus the response to an exception is delayed.

```
boolean allActive = true;
while (allActive) {
    for (Future<?> future : futures) {
        if (!future.isDone()) {
             allActive = false;
             break;
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(50);
}
```

What other options do I have? Or am I approaching the problem wrong?
Shouldn't I use a ScheduledExecutorService at all and implement the schedule myself in my own thread?

Example code, try change the order to the future list! I want the behavior you get if you add handle before handle2 but the order of the list shouldn't matter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {

    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        Future<?> handle = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("No exception!");
                if (i > 2) {
                    System.out.println("Exception!");
                    throw new RuntimeException("foo");
                }
                i++;
            }
        }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        Future<?> handle2 = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Running!");
            }
        }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


        List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        futures.add(handle2);
        futures.add(handle);

        try {
            for (Future<?> future : futures) {
                future.get();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            scheduler.shutdownNow();
            System.out.println(scheduler.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            System.out.println("Shuwdown complete");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might like Guava's [`ListenableFuture`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) for tasks like this.

Comment: Have you thought of using "isCancelled()"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a Listener or Observer-Like pattern:

```
interface IFutureListener{
    void onException( Throwable t );
}


final IFutureListener errHandler = new IFutureListener(){
     @override public void onException( Throwable t ){
          // shutdown Service here
     }
};
// ...
Future<?> handle = scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        final IFutureListener callback = errHandler;
        public void run() {
            try{
            System.out.println("No exception!");
            if (i > 2) {
                System.out.println("Exception!");
                throw new RuntimeException("foo");
            }
            i++;
            }
            catch( Exception ex ){
                callback.onException(ex);
            }
        }
    }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

You still might need some tweaks to this, but this is the gist of it.

Guava's ListenableFuture as @dimo414 writes in comment will give you something similar. But if you do not want / are not allowed to use 3rd parties, this is a way you can implement it yourself.

Thanks to @efekctive: I also suggest logging exceptions. They should almost never just be swallowed silently except you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I will take a look at Guava but this looks like it should do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Just make the class where main is the listener and provide the mean to distinguish which is the future causing the exception

Comment: @efekctive This was just an example to get him started. You could also make the interface method's signature `void onException(Throwable t, Runnable r)` and call it like `onException(ex, this)` ... you could tweak it in many many different ways. I based my suggestion on the question's code with a most simple way to get the behavior the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just thought that he needed to know what crashed.

Comment: @efekctive Good point actually. Exceptions that cannot be recovered from automatically should never be dismissed silently.